# Obtener lo meses del año ordenados de menor a mayor y en español a partir de una fecha en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito saber como extraer los meses del año de menor a mayor y en español a partir de un campo `fecha_nacimiento` que tengo en la base de datos.

Cuando lo hago con la función `EXTRACT()` me muestra solo los numeros de las posiciones de los meses,

En cambio, cuando lo hago con `Monthname()` me muestra los nombres de los meses pero en desorden (*empieza por cualquier mes y no desde enero*) y en ingles.

**Primero lo intente con MONTHNAME()**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");
$inicio = date("Y-01-01");
 $fin = date("Y-12-31");

$querymeses = 'SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total
   FROM pacientes WHERE YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) BETWEEN "'.$inicio.'" AND "'. $fin . '" GROUP BY mes ASC';
```

**Tambien lo hice con EXTRACT() de esta manera:**

```
$querymeses = 'SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total
   FROM pacientes WHERE YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) BETWEEN "'.$inicio.'" AND "'. $fin . '" GROUP BY mes ASC';
```

Ninguna de las dos funciones me devuelve totalmente lo que quiero, ya que con `extract()` obtengo los meses ordenados de menor a mayor pero en números, mientras que `monthname()` me devuelve los nombres de los meses pero de forma desordenada y en ingles.

Comment: `setLocale()` afecta el entorno de PHP, mas no la conexión de MySQL; para afectar la conexión debes usar la variable de MySQL [`lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html).

Answer (score 2):

Para que `MySQL` devuleva el nombre de los meses en español necesitas estableceer la variable [`lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names) que especifica la configuración regional.
Por ejemplo:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_AR';
```

Luego, para obtener el resultado ordenado por el mes tenes que ordenar por el número del mes.
Por ejemplo:

```
MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) AS mesNum
```

*Comentario*:
*Si queres saber todos los pacientes que cumplen en los distintos meses no es necesario filtrar por año.*

La consulta final podría ser:

```sql
SET lc_time_names = 'es_AR';

SELECT 
    MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) AS mesNum,
    MONTHNAME(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM pacientes
GROUP BY mesNum, mes
ORDER BY mesNum ASC;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1fq2vbKBtPdWDyrjMvPEG/2)</kbd>